# boton guardar y boton añadir en HTML,PHP, JAVASCRIPT Y MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

tengo un embrollo con un formulario, tengo un formulario llamado form_validacion.PHP donde lleno varios text box y tengo dos botones uno me funciona para agregar (el usuario puede contestar varias veces el formulario y llena una tabla en la misma pagina y regresa la variable $_Proceso) y otro para continuar (me manda a otra pagina y tiene que mandar la variable $_Proceso) cabe mencionar que los botones también tienen funciones de javascript.

este es mi formulario.

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="PHP/GuardarMetodoque.php" method="POST" novalidate>
               <!--    codigo de formulario -->
 
<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="metodoque" value="metodoque" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Añadir Riesgo</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="Anadirriesgo1" value="Anadirriesgo1" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ID_proceso" value="<?php echo $_id; ?>">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Regresar" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
                         </div>
                       </div>
                     </form>
```

como ven en el form llamo al archivo PHP/GuardarMetodoque.php que este tiene la funcion para guardar el formulario regresar a mi pagina form_validacion.PHP y regresar la variable $_Id_Proceso

```html
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$_Anadir_Riesgo_que = stripslashes($_POST["Anadirriesgo1"]);
 
 
if  (isset($_Anadir_Riesgo_que) && $_Anadir_Riesgo_que == "Anadirriesgo1")
        {
        $ID_Proceso = stripslashes($_POST["ID_proceso"]);
        $ID_QUE = stripslashes($_POST["ID_QUE"]);
        $_que = stripslashes($_POST["que"]);
        $_Riesgo = stripslashes($_POST["riesgo_que"]);
        $_criticidad = stripslashes($_POST["Criticidad"]);
        $_Ocurrencia = stripslashes($_POST["Ocurrencia"]);
        $_Reaccion = stripslashes($_POST["Reaccion"]);
        $_Valor = stripslashes($_POST[""]);
        $_Decision = stripslashes($_POST["Decision"]);
        $_Plan_Accion = stripslashes($_POST["Plan_Accion"]);
        $query = "INSERT INTO riesgo_metodo_que (Id_Proceso,Id_Metodo,que,Riesgo, Criticidad, Ocurrencia, Reaccion, Valor, Decision, Plan_Accion)
        VALUES ('$ID_Proceso', '$ID_QUE', '$_que', '$_Riesgo', '$_criticidad', '$_Ocurrencia', '$_Reaccion', '$_Valor', '$_Decision', '$_Plan_Accion'); ";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) die($conn->error);
        header("Location: ../form_validation.php?varG=$ID_Proceso");
        exit;
        }
 
?>
```

esto funciona bien solo que aquí se complica la cuestión, al dar el boton continuar me manda nueva mente a llamar el archivo PHP/GuardarMetodoque.php y de igual tengo este código para recuperar la variable $_Proceso
después de guardar el formulario

```html
<?php
                              $_ID_proceso = (isset($_GET['varG'])?stripslashes($_GET['varG']):"0");
                              $query = "SELECT proceso.id,proceso.Nombre_proceso FROM proceso
                                        INNER JOIN riesgo_metodo_que ON proceso.id = riesgo_metodo_que.Id_Proceso
                                        WHERE riesgo_metodo_que.Id_Proceso = ".$_ID_proceso."";
                            $result = $conn->query($query);
                            if (!$result) die($conn->error);
 
                             while ($_row = mysqli_fetch_array($_result)){
                             $_proceso = $_row["proceso.Nombre_proceso"];
                             $_id = $_row["proceso.id"];
                        }
                        ?>
```

y este código me sirve para recuperar la variable $_Proceso cuando entro al formulario

```html
<?php
              $_proceso = (isset($_GET['var'])?stripslashes($_GET['var']):"");
              $query = "SELECT id,Nombre_proceso FROM proceso WHERE Nombre_proceso = '$_proceso'";
                $_result = $conn->query($query);
                if (!$_result) die($conn->error);
 
                while ($_row = mysqli_fetch_array($_result)){
                    $_proceso = $_row["Nombre_proceso"];
                    $_id = $_row["id"];
                        }
              ?>
```

y aquí esta otro problema cuando guardo varios formularios y doy clic en el botón añadir ya no me regresa la variable $_Proceso.

si me pueden ayudar para resolver este embrollo en el que estoy metido.

este es mi codigo javascript

```js
     <script>
            function continuar(){
                var Num = document.getElementById("multiprica").innerHTML;
                var Acc = document.getElementById("Plan_Accion").value;                
                if(Num > 4){ 
                if (Acc.length==""){
                    alert("Es Requerida una Accion Correctiva");
                    return false;
                }
              }
            }
         </script>
```

Comment: Por que estos botones llaman al mismo metodo javascript?                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button>                 Deberias postear tu codigo javascript para revisarlo
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Añadir Riesgo</button>

Comment: El código compartido presenta graves problemas de seguridad, deberías leer sobre inyección SQL y cómo prevenirla en PHP.

Comment: ¿Y por qué te haces tanto lío enviando a otra página y demás cuando con Javascript/Ajax puedes usar la misma página para diferentes procesos? Debes tener en cuenta que hoy día es importante tener muy en cuenta lo que se conoce como *experiencia de usuario* a la hora de programar. Una aplicación donde el usuario tenga que cambiar continuamente de página sin necesidad significa una aplicación mal concebida desde el punto de vista de *experiencia del usuario*.

Comment: gracias por sus consejos @AlvaroMontoro pero ahorita no es el tema que quiero revisar,

Comment: @SoniaToledo ya agregue el codigo javascript y me funciona para revisar si tiene un campo lleno en caso de que sea una cantidad mayor a 4